# How to make copy UIView and save accessibilityId programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I use:

```
extension UIView {
    func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
    }
}
```

But my copy is losing the accessibility identifier.

```
copyView.accessibilityIdentifier == nil
```

How to save that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an Apple bug. You should really report this on [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

That said, you can work around the issue as follows:

```
extension UIView {
    func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        let copy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
        copy.accessibilityIdentifier = accessibilityIdentifier
        return copy
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I implement a synchronous loop like this
`for sub1,sub2 in main,copy {
  sub2.property = sub1.property
}`